# 4D derivation of any quadric surfaces?

Tags: surfaces, projective-geometry

One can derive all 2D conic sections via operations of a couple 3D objects using [Dandelin spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres).  Is it possible to derive 3D quadric surfaces via operations of a select few 4D objects?